# Styling the object while we are dragging it

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I just want to know how to change the style of the object we are dragging using HTML5's Drag/Drop API. I searched over the net but found nothing! Saw this tutorial but it did't gave me information about styling the object while dragging it.

Any solutions to this problem?

Moreover, Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is partially possible
In HTML5 you are not able to change the style of the ghost object
but you are able to change the default ghost object with the
setDragImage method from the DataTransfer object.
Made an example here (the blu div will become a red div when dragged):

```
  <style>
      #div1{
        background-color:blue;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
      }
      #div2{
        background-color:red;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
      }
    </style>
    ...
    <div id="div1" draggable="true" ></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="div2" ></div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(document.getElementById('div2'),50,50);
      });
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftX3C/

So you can't change the style, but have a hidden element from which to use as a ghost image. It can also be an img or a canvas.

I recommend the following tutorial about html5 drag and drop:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

also read about the DataTransfer object after you finish that tut:
[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)

Comment: Worked fine! i'm added also e.offsetX, e.offsetY as 2th and 3th params instead 50, 50. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn’t change the image _while_ dragging, but only at the beginning of dragging.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid , did you find a way to  change the style while dragging?

Comment: No @Lossan, I didn’t. I then gave up with the Drag-and-Drop API (for this and other reasons) and happily solved my problems with a JavaScript library.