# Drag and Drop related issue

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way of modifying html drag and drop according to our requirement?

Requirement:-

1.whenever we drag its opacity get decreased,in this case I don't want      to decrease its opacity.
 2. When we drag instead of original image or div its clone get drag,In this case I don't want to drag its clone instead its original div or image.
 3. Any way to get back all drag content back to its original position.

Note:I am taking about only drag n drop of HTML5.

Comment: I'm sure it is. Start with API docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: To answer 1): opacity change is done by the browser, so to change that you need to define your own drag-and-drop function (see [Controlling the appearance of the HTML5 drag and drop effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055044/controlling-the-appearance-of-the-html5-drag-and-drop-effect). One solution is to use [JQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#visual-feedback)