# Is it possible to prevent an image from being selected on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a website that displays a table. The table header(s) contain a text description and a question mark image (Users can hover over the image to get some help).

But I've got a request to allow users to highlight the table and copy it without the image (Via click and drag).

Is this possible? I tried the suggestion in here

[Preventing an image from being draggable or selectable without using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906789/preventing-an-image-from-being-draggable-or-selectable-without-using-js)

With no luck.

Can I mark an image as 'no-copy' or 'no-select'?

Comment: @azrael you might want to consider reading the entire question in stead of only the title. Then you would know that image protection is of no concern to the OP.

Comment: Instead of `img` tag use a fixed-size `div` with css property `background-image` pointing to your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `div` element and use the `background-image` property to set the background image to be the question mark for the `div` element.

The div element contains no text whatsoever, thus cannot be selected.

Just for clarification:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>header1</th>
    <th>header2 <div class="question-mark"></div></th>
  </tr>
</thead>


.question-mark{
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    background-image: url("question_mark.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked unreasonably well. I also added display: inline-block; to .question-mark to keep the div from wrapping onto a new line in the Table Header.

Comment: Sorry I left it out, please feel free to edit the answer to improve.

Answer (score 0):

As other users suggested, you can use a div as an image.

However, if you wish to keep your image an image, you can use

```
var img = document.querySelector("#notToDragImg");
img.onselectstart = function(){
                    return false;
                };
```

to prevent selection of your image (and no jQuery needed)

Answer (score 0):

Prevent an image from being selected using CSS

```
img {
  user-select: none !important;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```