# Undraggable Image

Tags: jquery, image, pseudo-element

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407898/3703461

I've had a look at this code, and found a very peculiar occurrance to it.

I've made it into a pluggable format into jQuery as such:

```
$.fn.unselectableCSS = function(){
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  var css =   '.unselectable {\r\n'+
                '-moz-user-select:none;\r\n'+
                '-webkit-user-select:none;\r\n'+
                '-ms-user-select:none;\r\n'+
                'user-select:none;\r\n'+
                '-webkit-user-drag:none;\r\n'+
                'user-drag:none;\r\n'+
              '}\r\n';

  $(style).html(css);
}

$.fn.unselectable = function(){
  $(this).addClass('unselectable')
         .attr('unselectable','on')
         .attr('draggable','false')
         .on('dragstart',function(){return false;});
  $(this).find( '*' )
         .attr( 'draggable', 'false' )
         .attr( 'unselectable', 'on' );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).unselectableCSS();
  $('img').unselectable();
});
```

And it works perfectly! Except under one circumstance (so far)

If an image is clicked through a before/after element (in this case a before element with a background image) the image behind it becomes draggable again! (sometimes this happens right away, sometimes quite a few clicks are needed)

Any ideas what could have caused this?

Comment: Please add some HTML/CSS, jsfiddle, or webpage demonstrating the issue. But IIRC it may be caused by Javascript being unable to access `:before` or `:after` since they aren't a part of the DOM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788990/access-the-css-after-selector-with-jquery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vfgg4863/ Think this demonstrates the issue, not sure without an HTML/CSS sample from the OP.   Click the JSFiddle logo and drag a few times, eventually the cursor changes from `text` to `not-allowed` during the drag operation. Right click the image and it reverts.