# Disable drag for any object in firefox addon popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developping an extension on Chrome / Firefox which has a popup composed of different graphic elements. I don't want user to drag and drop these items from this popup. To disable drag in Chrome, I can use this css code:

```
* {
    user-drag: none;
    -ms-user-drag: none;
    -moz-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;

    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;

    text-decoration: none;
}
```

But this doesn't work in Firefox. Is there any css attribute which could work in this case?

Here is a minimal version: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4k6nM18722gNjY5VjVpREhpRTQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **Disable Dragging via Brute Force:**

To disable dragging on the entire popup/document, you can do any one of the following:

- Add the following lines to your *popup.js* file:

```js
function noDrag(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
document.addEventListener('dragstart',noDrag,true);
```

- Or add this line to *popup.js*:

```js
document.addEventListener('dragstart',function(event){event.preventDefault();},true);
```

- Or change the `<html>` line in *popup.html* to:

```html
<html ondragstart='event.preventDefault();'>
```

My personal preference is to use the named `noDrag` function. The named function instead of the closure merely because, at some point in the future, I might want to be selective about which elements have drag disabled. Having it named allows the same function to be re-used, or removed as a listener from an element, should that be desirable. The JavaScript instead of the HTML because A) you already have a JavaSctipt file for the popup and B) my opinion of the `onxxxxx` event attributes/properties is that they should be avoided when reasonable. If there was not already a JavaScript file associated with this popup, I would use the HTML `ondragstart` method.

### **How it is supposed to work:**

The following does not disable dragging on `<a>` and `<img>` elements. The specs and documentation say that it is supposed to work to disable dragging. I need to delve further into the Firefox source code to figure out why it is not working.

In Firefox (and the HTML specification), the element being draggable is controlled by the  [`draggable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-draggable).  For images and links, the default value is `true`. For everything else, the default is `false`.  You will either need to have `draggable="false"` on all such elements in your HTML, or use JavaScript to `setAttribute('draggable',false)`, or [`element.draggable = false;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) on all such elements.

Firefox does not have a CSS property which can be used to control if an element is draggable.

For more information see:

- [Preventing an image from being draggable or selectable without using JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906789/preventing-an-image-from-being-draggable-or-selectable-without-using-js)
- [draggable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable)
- [Drag Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations)
- [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)
- [WHATWG HTML Living Standard (The definition of `draggable` in that specification.)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-draggable-attribute)
- [HTML5.2 (The definition of 'draggable' in that specification.)](http://w3c.github.io/html/editing.html#the-draggable-attribute)

Comment: draggable attribute seems to not work for extensions in popup. Whatever if I use it in JS or HTML, elements are still draggable.

Comment: @Nucktrooper, Please provide a [mcve] of an extension opening a panel where you have such an issue, so we can duplicate the problem.

Comment: Minimal version added to the question.

Comment: @Nucktrooper, Thanks for the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have updated the answer with a tested and working brute force method to disable dragging on the entire popup.