# How to pass draggable attribute to <img> in Next.js Image component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to prevent dragging of ghost image.

Normal way:
`<img draggable="false">`

But I don't know how to set it to `<Image />` component

Image component docs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Edit:

`<Image draggable="false"/>` works, but for Firefox, we need add the same atrribute to parent `<a>` and in CSS it can't be `user-select: none` for `img` and `div`

It's still difference between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Adding a CSS rule like `pointer-events: none` should be easier

Comment: The Image does support a `ref`, so maybe you can also try to work with that and `onDragStart`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Next.js but if it doesn't allow you to add draggable attribute then you can set it in CSS. I hope the following link helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12906840/8900144